# how to bring current activity front on notification clicked?

Tags: android, notifications

When any music player playing a song, clicked on its notification it will show us a current position of tracks, how?

I am creating an application, here I pressed on one button and its visibility set to GONE, and another button appears on its place like ON/OFF button. when I pressed ON, notification appears ON button GONE and OFF button VISIBLE, after that I am minimizing running application. Now when I clicked on notification, it have to show my last view of application where OFF is VISIBLE, ON is GONE instead of it, it launch the screen again where ON VISIBLE and OFF is GONE.

I used this code for that,

```
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    mNm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;        // icon from resources
    CharSequence tickerText = "my text";              // ticker-text
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
    Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
    CharSequence contentTitle = "my title";  // message title
    CharSequence contentText = "my message!";      // message text

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    notificationIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DontTouchMyDroidActivity.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
            // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
    notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You need can pass data in your `Intent`. There are 2 parts to this:

### 1)

When you **create** your `Intent`, you add extra data to that intent. For example, you could add a `String` called ON_VISIBLE, and set it to "true". Here is some code to add extras to the intent that you created:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DontTouchMyDroidActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("ON_VISIBLE", "true");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("SOME_OTHER_DATA", "look at help for putExtra()");
```

This adds extra information as part of a `Bundle` to the `Intent` (look for help on `Bundle` & `Intent.putExtras()`)

### 2)

When you **receive** your `Intent`, you need to extract that information from it. Here is some code to take the `Bundle` out of your `Intent`. You can then use the values to determine if you want to show or hide the buttons.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // retrieve bundle extras passed into this intent
    String onButtonVisible = "false";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        onButtonVisible = extras.getString("ON_VISIBLE");
    }

    Boolean makeVisible = Boolean.valueOf(onButtonVisible);
    if (makeVisible)
    {
        // make your ON button visible
    }
}
```

This is the method that will get called if your `Activity` is being created.

If your `Activity` is still alive in the background, then you need to do something similar in the method `Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)`

```
/** Called if activity is being brought in from background by a new intent. */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras = intent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        onButtonVisible = extras.getString("ON_VISIBLE");
    }

    // do something similar here
}
```

---

So the short answer is that you add "extras" to your `Intent` when you create it. These "extras" are added to a `Bundle` which you can then query when your `Activity` is launched. And also, to know that there are 2 methods you need to know about where you can query the extras.

A bit of Googling on Intent, extras, Bundle, should fill in any info that I have left out.